# AutoLisp - get-universal-time

Tags: autolisp

I am new in Lisp. I need to call datetime function. But I stuck at getting date time. Using UTC.

The code is

```
  (defun C:test ()
  (system-clock nil (get-universal-time))
  )
```

The error:

```
Command: TEST
; error: no function definition: GET-UNIVERSAL-TIME
```

Anyone can help ? I'm using VisualLisp

Comment: Do you have a Visuallisp manual? It should list the available functions.

Comment: AutoLisp does not have date manipulation functions. Take a look at [DATE (System Variable)](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/AutoCAD-Core/files/GUID-CBB24068-1654-4753-BE2E-1D0CE9700411-htm.html) and [Thread: How to get a date in a DD/MM/YY format?](http://forums.augi.com/showthread.php?43041-How-to-get-a-date-in-a-DD-MM-YY-format).

Comment: P.S. there is no `system-clock` either. You really can't look for functionality outside of the Autodesk documentation (i.e. from scheme or common lisp based libraries). AutoLisp is very stripped down and focused on working with AutoCAD objects.

Comment: Thanks @crashmstr for the reference. It helps

Comment: @crashmstr so that means we cannot use common lisp command in autolisp is it?

Comment: Correct, do not expect to be able to use any Common Lisp specific functionality. AutoLisp is much more like Scheme, but even then lacks many of those features too.

Answer (score 1):

There's a system variable called "CDATE", which has somehow more clear output than "DATE" system variable.

It gets the current date and time in your computer.

"CDATE"'s output format is "(4 digit year)(2 digit month)(2 digit day).(2 digit hours)(2 digit minutes)", and its in a decimal format like this 20170609.1410 for 2016/06/09 1:10 pm

So, to acquire current date in YYYY/MM/DD format your strategy will be like this:-

1- get the output and convert it to string

```
    (setq cur_date (rtos (getvar "CDATE")))
```

2- extract year, month and day

```
    (setq cur_year (substr cur_date 1 4))
    (setq cur_month (substr cur_date 5 2))
    (setq cur_day (substr cur_date 7 2))
```

3- construct your YYYY/MM/DD format

```
    (setq cur_date (strcat cur_year "/" cur_month "/" cur_day))
```

Comment: The current date may be more easily obtained using `(menucmd "m=$(edtime,0,yyyy/mo/dd)")`